# what are classical equivalents to "let it stand [however]" / "[yet/even though], let's suppose"?

Tags: idiom

I came across [this passage](http://www.monumenta.ch/latein/text.php?tabelle=Ambrosius&rumpfid=Ambrosius,%20De%20Officiis%20Ministrorum,%202,%20%20%2026&level=4&domain=&lang=1&id=&hilite_id=&satz=&string=&links=1&inframe=1&hide_apparatus=1) from Ambrosiu's *De Officiis Ministrorum* (Book II. ch. 26):

> Feralis igitur avaritia, illecebrosa pecunia, quae habentes contaminat, non habentes non iuvat. Esto tamen ut aliquando adiuvet pecunia, inferiorem tamen et ipsam desiderantem.

> Love of money, then, is deadly. Seductive is money, whilst it also defiles those who have it, and helps not those who have it not. Supposing that money sometimes is a help, yet it is only a help to a poor man who makes his want known. ([translation: Philip Schaff](http://www.documentacatholicaomnia.eu/03d/0339-0397,_Ambrosius,_De_Officiis_Ministrorum_Libri_Tres_%5BSchaff%5D,_EN.pdf))

I am interested in the expression *Esto tamen ut* - I was unbale to find this expression in classical sources - and also in post-classical it seems not so ubiquitous. What are the alternatives to convey the same sentiment? I thought of *"dicamus tamen"* but I can't really find it. The sentiment I am after is pretty much like "let it stand [however]" / "[yet/even though], let's suppose" - and close to "for the sake of the argument" (though even if *arguendo* were classical, I would prefer something else more innocent and less strict/formal -- that gives a real chance of the thing to be true without cynicism.)